# Visual studio Automatic Version and file versioning

Tags: git, visual-studio, versioning

I am using Visual Studio with Automatic Version to increment my file versions under some specific project conditions.

I also use Git as file versioning method.

Now, my Git settings seem not to include my project's Automatic Version, i.e. they only works on one of my machine. I actually don't know if it is because of some of my Git exclusions filters or because the file containing the Automatic Version settings is a Visual Studio setting which is not included in my project.

So to the point : where are Automatic Version settings stored and how can I make sure they are passed along with a Git commit.

**Bonus question:** how can I include the new version number as a Git-commit comment automatically in a post-build command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several layers in the application.
It turns out that, in order to commit the changes, you should store the parameters at project level which stores the changes in the *.csproj file.